# What does mBtc mean

Tags: terminology, divisibility

I’m using Electrum 3.3.8 and I recently made a sale and got 0.83 mBTC.

I’ve tried to convert the mBTC to USD. it says i have $5000+ but I was selling the product for only $6

[image: ct]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `m` prefix is a [SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes) prefix denoting `milli`, or one-thousandth of a known value.

Thus, 1 BTC = 1000 mBTC, or 1 mBTC = 0.001 BTC.

You appear to have 0.83 mBTC, which is 0.00083 BTC, or about 6 USD at current rates.